# I need to correct the code to return true if value is in array, otherwise return false. but this code return both of them using (for in) loop

Tags: java

```
int[] Scores={2,3,8,7,1,4,9};

int kema=7;
boolean T=true;
boolean F=false;

for(int value : Scores)
    if(kema == value) {
        System.out.println(T);
        break;
    }

system.out.println(F);
```

I need to correct the code to return true if value is in array, otherwise return false. but this code return both of them using (for in) loop.

Comment: Use a variable `boolean found` so that you can use an `if` / `else` instead that just breaking the loop.

Comment: @Satya it doesn't work it gives me this output [ false
false
false
true]

Comment: @Jack if you don't mind please , can you write the code using boolean found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8+ you can use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)**1** and something like

```
System.out.println(IntStream.of(Scores).anyMatch(x -> x == kema));
```

In earlier versions of Java, you might extract the *logic* to a method like

```
public static boolean contains(int[] arr, int val) {
    for (int v : arr) {
        if (v == val) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then call it like

```
System.out.println(contains(Scores, kema));
```

**1**<sub>Also, by convention, variables should start with lower case letter.</sub>

Comment: I'm just curious, but *under the hood* does the Java 8+ `IntStream` get converted to the earlier versions of Java implementation?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Something similar, if you look at the [`Stream.anyMatch(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) Javadoc, it says *this method evaluates the existential quantification of the predicate over the elements of the stream (for some x P(x))*; and I think that's what my version does but *existentialism* isn't really my philosophical forte.

Comment: @JonnyHenly `Stream.anyMatch(Predicate)` is guaranteed to return the same as the above looping code, but it works in a different manner. Streams are a different way to think about values: the JVM is allowed to rearrange the elements of rearrange and parallelize the operations on Streams unless the Stream is explicitly ordered. Generally, though not in all cases, using a Stream will be more performant because of these allowances.

Comment: @CAD97 oh wow that was very informative, I didn't realize that the JVM could rearrange and parallelize the operations. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3):

Like the user [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121747/jack) suggested in the comments to your question. Use a boolean to keep track of if the value was found in the array.

```
int[] Scores={2,3,8,7,1,4,9};

int kema = 7;
boolean T = true;
boolean F = false;
boolean found = false;

for(int value : Scores) {
    if(kema == value) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(found) {
    System.out.println(T);
} else {
    System.out.println(F);
}
```

You also don't need to have two booleans representing true and false, one boolean is either true or false. So the following could also work:

```
int[] Scores={2,3,8,7,1,4,9};

int kema = 7;
boolean found = false;

for(int value : Scores) {
    if(kema == value) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(found);
```